# How can I make nautilus use my installed FUSE file systems automatically?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, fuse

Is there a way to have Nautilus automatically use my FUSE file systems to (for example) open ISOs as folders, or archives as folders, or what ever other 'locations' FUSE supports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nautilus can't possibly 'know' any installed fuse driver because the fuse system does not advertise its drivers mount options and whereabouts by itself. There isn't even a common database defined where the installed fuse drivers register themselves yet.

Note also that the *gvfs* system handles URIs like `smb://` while the fuse driver underneath does not, therefore your preferred fuse driver needs to be supported by *gvfs* first before it can land in nautilus.

However, there are lots of nautilus-action scripts around that may accomplish what you need. And if you can type in the mount options by hand, a xfce-tool named `gigolo` can help you to keep your fuse mounts bookmarked.

Comment: I know what to do with tags, I just haven't gotten around to that one. Don't add that to your answer next time ;).